# Запись данных в поле типа HStore в Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Есть таблица такого вида:

```
                           Table "public.project"
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | bigint  |           | plain    |              |
 custom        | hstore  |           | extended |              |
```

В поле `custom` я хочу записать значение, не затирая значения которые уже содержаться в этом поле, вот таким способом:

```
UPDATE "project" set "custom" = "custom" || ('"testKey"=>"testValue"') where "id"=1;
```

Но если в этом поле никаких данных до этого не было, т.е. я пишу в него первый раз, то этот запрос не срабатывает.
Для того что бы он сработал нужно сделать запрос сначала в таком виде (этот запрос при повторном вызове перезаписывает уже существующие данные).

```
UPDATE "project" set(custom) =  ('"testKey" => "testValue"') where "id"=1;
```

И уже потом только у меня получается записать данные первым способом.

Получается что при первой записи данных мне нужен один sql запрос,а при последующих - другой.

**Вопрос**: как узнать что я пишу в поле впервые что бы определить какого вида sql мне щас нужно использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно у вас NULL дефолтный, а конкатенация NULL с hstore даёт NULL. Достаточно заменить в запросе NULL на пустой hstore через coalesce:

```
UPDATE "project" 
  set "custom" = coalesce("custom", '') || ('"testKey"=>"testValue"')
where "id"=1;
```

Comment: Супер, работает, почему то не заметил этого когда читал документацию, можете скинуть ссылку где я могу прочитать об этом?

Comment: О чём именно? Особенности конкатенации с NULL?

Comment: да,конкатенации с NULL!

Comment: Прямым текстом вроде бы не написано. Проверяется элементарно. Вообще многие операции с NULL'ом даёт NULL. Потому что это NULL - т.е. непонятно что. Непонятно что плюс 3 всё равно будет непонятно что